# How do I change the position of a drop down menu in Bootstrap? I tried using data-offset or data-reference but they didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, bootstrap-5

My dropdown menu starts from the left of the page and its position is not relative to the list items.

[image: 1]

```
<div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container justify-content-between">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ARARAT</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav  dropdown-menu-end mx-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle py-3 px-3" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                                role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Blog</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">d1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">d2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">d3</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">d4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle py-3 px-3" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                                role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Pages</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">P1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">P2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">P3</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">P4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-3" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Contact</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <button class="btn bg-transparent fs-6 PX-5 PY-5" type="submit">GET IN TOUCH</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Here I'm attaching a photo for the result I get... I want the list of (P1, P2, ...) be under the "pages" list item. Thank you

Comment: what you need is  a dropdown check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/ it will help you

Comment: Your problem is that  you didn't add dropdown class="nav-item dropdown" add dropdown here

Answer (score 0):

I think why your pages dropdown is not working is you gave the same id to your both dropdown menu.

```
id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
```

Try to change one of the dropdown'd id. Remember, If two Bootstrap dropdown menus have the same id and aria-labelledby values, the first dropdown will function correctly but the second dropdown will not work as expected.